# Why can't I get a floating point answer in Gforth?

Tags: forth, gforth

I heard that you just have to put an F in front of the operator and then put a (.) at the end to calculate the floating point number and then display it. But it gave me this answer:

```
2 3 F/ .       
:8: Floating-point stack underflow
2 3 >>>F/<<< .
Backtrace:
```

How can I get `0.66666667 ok`?

Comment: [Cross-posted to Quora](https://www.quora.com/My-Gforth-window-wont-let-me-do-anything-other-than-integer-math-How-can-I-get-floating-point-numbers-going-here) (essentially).

Answer (score 5):

You heard wrong.  Presumably whoever told you that meant that the period should be at the end of the operands, but that would make them double-precision values (no relation to double floats).  You need to put an `e` at the end of `2` and `3` to make them floats, write `f/` to divide them, and write `f.` to print:

```
in:  2e 3e f/ f.
out: 0.666666666666667 ok
```